# Reading data from a relational database into a LaTeX table

Tags: tables, luatex, lua

I'm using Tex Live 2009 on Debian squeeze. I can upgrade if I really, really  have to, but I'd rather not. I was wondering if it would be possible to do the following.

Given some data in a (relational) database, can I extract it and automatically format it in a LaTeX table, so one would not need to manually recreate the LaTeX table if the data changes? Could one do such a thing with Lua? One would normally use a suitable language database adaptor for this, and I see Lua has [LuaSQL](http://www.keplerproject.org/luasql/manual.html). I'd like to use PostgreSQL. I'm currently using version 8.4.

Solutions not involving Lua are also fine. Just to be clear, I don't know anything about Lua and my knowledge of LaTeX programming is also extremely skimpy. I'm looking for a recipe which I can adapt if necessary. While this is not really important for my current use case, it seems like a useful general technique if possible.

Comment: Since you proably want to use `LuaTeX`, I strongly recommend you install the latest TeXLive 2011.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Well, it looks like Norbert has now put packages of Tex Live 2011 in experimental, so I'll give it a try.

Comment: That's actually TL2012 beta. `:-)`

Comment: @MartinSchröder Is there anything in particular one need to watch out for?

Answer (score 27):

Let's assume you want this output:

[image: table from sql database]

If you use LuaTeX, the most innovative way is to include the luasql bindings in your program.

First create a simple database (`createdb.txt`):

```
CREATE TABLE people(
name  varchar(50),
email varchar(50)
);
INSERT INTO "people" VALUES('Jose das Couves','jose@couves.com');
INSERT INTO "people" VALUES('Manoel Joaquim','manoel.joaquim@cafundo.com');
INSERT INTO "people" VALUES('Maria das Dores','maria@dores.com');
```

and fill it with `sqlite3 luasql-test < createdb.txt`

The next step is to create a simple LuaLaTeX document and read the file into the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
require("luasql.sqlite3")

env = assert (luasql.sqlite3())
-- connect to data source
con = assert (env:connect("luasql-test"))
-- retrieve a cursor
cur = assert (con:execute"SELECT name, email from people")
-- print all rows, the rows will be indexed by field names
row = cur:fetch ({}, "a")
tex.sprint([[\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}\toprule]])
tex.sprint([[Name & email \\\midrule]])
while row do
  tex.sprint(-2,row.name)
  tex.sprint("&")
  tex.sprint(-2, row.email)
  tex.sprint("\\\\")
  -- reusing the table of results
  row = cur:fetch (row, "a")
end
tex.sprint([[\bottomrule\end{tabular}]])
-- close everything
cur:close()
con:close()
env:close()
\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

(The example is taken from the [luasql home page](http://www.keplerproject.org/luasql/examples.html).)

I have skipped the worst part: compiling and installing. This is highly system dependent, but I will list some steps/pitfalls.

- On MacOS X, you can't use the `sqlite3.so` from luasql directly, because the `luatex` binary misses some symbols. So you need to compile your own non-stripped luatex binary (`./build.sh --nostrip`) and use that instead. It needs to be placed at the "original" version in the tex tree. If you have done that, you can use `sqlite3.so` from the luasql project. The same might be true on other unix systems. See [the entry 666 in the bug tracker](http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=555).
- Create a directory called `luasql` in your document directory and place the generated library there.
- You need LuaTeX version > 0.46.0. Therefore texlive 2011 might be the best choice.
- I have downloaded the source distribution of luasql and compiled it myself. I don't know if the luarocks based installation can be used as well (probably it can).

Comment: I've just heard that on linux it works fine with luarocks (luasql/mysql). The paths have to be set, but otherwise it worked out of the box.

Comment: A problem is how to point luatex to the lua module installation. I see there are a couple of question, namely http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14361/installing-lua-modules-for-use-in-lualatex and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42878/installing-lua-modules-for-use-in-lualatex-the-sequel, but they don't help me. Like the latter questioner, I'm using Debian.

Comment: I have not been able to use `luasql-sqlite3` module, but I have succeeded in using the `lsqlite3` module.

Comment: Please see [my slight modification of this answer as an answer to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/491057/3406). That answer works for me out of the box on the uncoming Debian stable. Namely, Debian Buster.

Answer (score 13):

The following code was motivated by a discussion in the chatroom. The idea here is to leave the data retrieval and processing to an external entity, set a `.tex` template that will hold the data, populate it and generate the final `.tex` file.

This is what template engines basically do. Although we can exploit Lua (see Patrick's great answer), sometimes you might rely on just a `.tex` template for the sake of simplicity. `:)`

Here we go, the code is fractionated to include some comments on what's happening in each part. I opted to code a small script in Python and rely solely on hardcoded data and template to ease the process.

```python
from xml.dom import minidom
from Cheetah.Template import Template
```

I decided to stick with some data expressed in the XML format because it was just a plain example of how to get data and incorporate it to TeX. Of course, the way we acquire content is irrelevant now, since we are just interested on how the data object is represented in our script. `:)`

I used `minidom` to read the XML excerpt and the [Cheetah](http://cheetahtemplate.org/) template engine to help me produce the resulting `.tex` file. For now, those are just imports, we will discuss implementation in the next steps.

```python
def getNodeValue(node, key):
    return node.getElementsByTagName(key)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue

def getData(source):
    a = []
    b = minidom.parseString(source)
    c = b.firstChild
    for d in c.childNodes:
        if d.nodeType == 1:
            e = {}
            e['name'] = getNodeValue(d, 'name')
            e['surname'] = getNodeValue(d, 'surname')
            e['grade'] = float(getNodeValue(d, 'grade'))
            a.append(e)
    return a
```

Those two functions were written just to help me traverse the XML content and fetch the data I want to use. The result will be an array containing dictionaries in the form

```python
{
    'name' : 'John',
    'surname' : 'Doe',
    'grade' : 10
}
```

extracted from the following XML, represented in the very own Python code as a raw string (note the `r` prepended in the string definition):

```python
xml = r"""<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<persons>

    <person>
        <name>Paulo</name>
        <surname>Cereda</surname>
        <grade>3.6</grade>
    </person>

    <person>
        <name>Enrico</name>
        <surname>Gregorio</surname>
        <grade>8.9</grade>
    </person>

    <person>
        <name>David</name>
        <surname>Carlisle</surname>
        <grade>8.8</grade>
    </person>

</persons>"""
```

Now, let's start the fun part. Once we have everything ready, let's read the XML content, parse it and create the array. I do this by calling the `getData` function defined previously. Just to be fancy, I apply a `sorted` function to the resulting array providing a lambda function that sets the order by the `name` key:

```python
data = sorted(getData(xml), key=lambda y: y['name'])
```

The `data` variable contains an array of dictionaries. Now let's create our `.tex` template, pretty much along the same lines we did with our XML file, that is, through a raw string:

```python
template = r"""\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{llS}
\hline
Name & Surname & {Grade}\\
\hline
#for $person in $data
$person['name'] & $person['surname'] & $person['grade']\\
#end for
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}"""
```

The template is pretty straightforward, it's a simple `.tex` file which will give us a `tabular` environment. The interesting part is:

```
#for $person in $data
$person['name'] & $person['surname'] & $person['grade']\\
#end for
```

This part is part of the [Cheetah language description](http://cheetahtemplate.org/docs/users_guide_html/users_guide.html#SECTION000610000000000000000). Simply put, this is a `for` loop where we iterate through all dictionaries in the `data` array. Note that `$` is used as a placeholder and not as math mode, as we are used in TeX. Don't worry with them, they'll be gone once we merge everything. `:)` Since we are dealing with a dictionary, we access values from its keys, so `$person['name']` will return the person's name. `:)`

Now, let's create the template from the source above and add the `data` array associated with a key, and print the template. I should output the merging to a new file, but for now, let's just print the resulting code to the terminal:

```python
definition = Template(source=template, searchList=[ { 'data': data } ])
print(definition)
```

And we are done. `:)`

Let me post the code as a whole, just for easy copy and paste:

```python
from xml.dom import minidom
from Cheetah.Template import Template

def getNodeValue(node, key):
    return node.getElementsByTagName(key)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue

def getData(source):
    a = []
    b = minidom.parseString(source)
    c = b.firstChild
    for d in c.childNodes:
        if d.nodeType == 1:
            e = {}
            e['name'] = getNodeValue(d, 'name')
            e['surname'] = getNodeValue(d, 'surname')
            e['grade'] = float(getNodeValue(d, 'grade'))
            a.append(e)
    return a

xml = r"""<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<persons>

    <person>
        <name>Paulo</name>
        <surname>Cereda</surname>
        <grade>3.6</grade>
    </person>

    <person>
        <name>Enrico</name>
        <surname>Gregorio</surname>
        <grade>8.9</grade>
    </person>

    <person>
        <name>David</name>
        <surname>Carlisle</surname>
        <grade>8.8</grade>
    </person>

</persons>"""

data = sorted(getData(xml), key=lambda y: y['name'])

template = r"""\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{llS}
\hline
Name & Surname & {Grade}\\
\hline
#for $person in $data
$person['name'] & $person['surname'] & $person['grade']\\
#end for
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}"""

definition = Template(source=template, searchList=[ { 'data': data } ])
print(definition)
```

In order to run this code, we need a Python interpreter (mine is `Python 2.7.5`) and the Cheetah template engine. I'm almost sure you can install it via your favourite package manager, say

```
# yum install python-cheetah
```

or probably via `pip`:

```
pip install Cheetah
```

Let's run the code now, shall we? `:)` Allons-y!

```
paulo@alexandria ~$ python mycode.py 
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{llS}
\hline
Name & Surname & {Grade}\\
\hline
David & Carlisle & 8.8\\
Enrico & Gregorio & 8.9\\
Paulo & Cereda & 3.6\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The resulting `.tex` file produces the following output:

[image: Quack]

And that's it. `:)`

Comment: Works flawlessly. Nice work.

Comment: @egreg has the higher grade score! Yay!

Answer (score 9):

**TeX dbi**
[River Valley Technology](http://river-valley.com) publishes a free software called [TeX dbi](http://river-valley.com/tex-dbi/). I have never used it, but according to the description at the [home page](http://river-valley.com/tex-dbi/), the software

> enables TeX to talk to SQL compliant database engines and generate beautiful reports.

I even found an [article](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb23-1/anilkumar.pdf) describing `TeX dbi`, see [TUGboat](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/), [Volume 23 (2002)](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb23-1/anilkumar.pdf). The program can be downloaded from [Sarovar (TeX dbi)](http://sarovar.org/projects/texdbi/). The file at Sarovar seems pretty old, so I recommend to contact authors to verify that this is the last version.

**SQLTeX**
At the [CTAN Catalogue](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg) you will find a product called [SQLTeX](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/SQLTeX). I have neither used that, but according to the introduction in the readme-file:

> SQLTeX is a preprocessor to enable the use of SQL statements in LaTeX.
>   It is a perl script that reads an input file containing the SQL commands,
>   and writes a LaTeX file that can be processed with your LaTeX package.

Comment: I don't see where one can get TeX dbi from. Do you have a link for this?

Comment: @FaheemMitha I have added a link to http://sarovar.org/projects/texdbi/ in the reply.

Answer (score 8):

This is rather a complimentary answer to the other answers provided by other posters. The major issue with the approach you are requesting is how do you enter the data from a practical point of view. If you are going to be doing SQL inserts you might as well be writing TeX macros.

```
INSERT INTO "people" VALUES('Jose das Couves','jose@couves.com');
INSERT INTO "people" VALUES('Manoel Joaquim','manoel.joaquim@cafundo.com');
INSERT INTO "people" VALUES('Maria das Dores','maria@dores.com');
```

can be more difficult than:

```
\R people,Jose das Couves,jose@couves.com;
\R people,Manoel Joaquim,manoel.joaquim@cafundo.com;
\R people,Maria das Dores,maria@dores.com;
```

Another *very promising* approach is to create your own special markup with the [interpreter](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/luatex/generic/interpreter), package which I consider as one of the current developments that might edge (la)TeX in a better direction.

If your records are as simple as that, you can use an approach as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19761/963, it can be less typing work, your records will survive for another thirty years and will not be depended on any other technology other than (La)TeX. The entries will also be edited in your favorite editor.

If the records are more complicated the TeX approach might be more involved, cumbersome and error prone. In this case your proposed method has an advantage.

I would start with getting some GUI tools to make the entry of the records easier. In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332250/windows-gui-tool-for-sqlite3 there are links to quite a few of them (I tried 2-3) and so far `Lita` seems like a good tool. Personally I would opt for a slightly different GUI and even Database tool. I would rather use MySQL and a browser.

Installation can be as easy as installing WAMP and MySQL and you can have a great interface going in a few minutes for creating a Relational Database. WAMP comes prepackaged with `phpMyAdmin` and `sqlbuddy`. The latter is less mature but currently my tool of choice. Similar tools exist for Python, Ruby, Perl and possibly Lua via the Kepler project.

I have tried hard to get `sqlite3` and `wxLua` to work together with `pdfLuaLaTeX` and although I haven't given up yet, I haven't managed to achieve it. I have narrowed down the issue though and is probably path settings via `kpathsea`. If you do get them right please let us know your installation steps.

There is also the issue of exporting the data back to LuaLaTeX and the format to be used.
My own experience so far is that for most typesetting type of problems the database schema is not relational and you better off with either a purely TeX solution or an XML type of solution (aka look at ConTeXt). For simple relational databases the `webfront` solution works very well; I have got one that does letters, stores metadata for the correspondence, picks up addresses etc. and exports LaTeX.

For simpler structured data (such as exports from lab experiments), simple CSV solutions with `pgfplotstable` and other CSV LaTeX tools are to be preferred.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful and comprehensive response, Yiannis. The use case I have in mind is for plotting numerical values, where the values are generated by a computer program. In this case one would not be manually writing SQL inserts. However, writing the data from the database to a csv file and the importing the csv file into LaTeX is certainly a feasible (and less hi-tech) approach. I can't at the moment see any compelling disadvantages to using the csv approach, except that it adds a layer of indirection and corresponding overhead.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I agree with you that if the data are generated by computer your approach is the better choice. If you developed the software, it might be worth to cut the middle layer and export straight the pgfplots commands and data or whatever else you using.

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment to Patrick's post, I haven't got the lua db approach to work yet. The problem is that luatex doesn't (out of the box on Debian) know where the lua module installations are. I think this *is* something that should work out of the box for a OS, that, like Debian, provides both a lua installation as well as luatex. I hope to follow up on this further, and will update my question if I do. I'd be interested to hear more details about what difficulties you have faced.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I had exactly the same issues like you except on a Windows machine. One normal way to by-pass the issue is to drop the modules into the same working directory as well. However, in this case since the modules are looking for the Lua installation path they did not work. When I get some time I will try and add them to the `lualibs` package and see what happens. There are also `.dll` files or `.so` in your case. These might need recompiling and a knowledge of `C++` (this is possibly why Patrick's installation worked, he recompiled).

Comment: Hi Yiannis. Thanks for the clarification. I believe the correct way to resolve this is to tell luatex where the modules are located. This should be possible, but I don't know how. I assume that either the Tex Live or the luatex project should be able to give directions. I have not been able to find any documentation except the tex.sx questions I linked to, though.

Answer (score 5):

If you're able to create a CSV from your database, then I would recommend using the [datatool](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool) package

Comment: In my experience, datatool quickly makes compiling the document horribly slow.

Answer (score 4):

This is a minor rewrite of [topskip's answer from 2012](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48233/3406). That answer has never worked for me, but in 2019 it's fixable with a couple of minor tweaks. I'm currently using Debian testing/Buster, which will soon be Debian 10. This answer was tested with the TeX Live prerelease corresponding to the Debian TeX Live packages version `2018.20181218.49446-1`.

The following code works on my Debian Buster installation, provided I have the Lua Debian package `lua-sql-sqlite3` installed. And of course, LuaTeX. That's available in the TeX Live Debian package `texlive-luatex`, assuming you use the TeX Live Debian packages.

After the code there are some notes and commentary.

First create a simple database (`createdb.txt`):

```
CREATE TABLE people(
name  varchar(50),
email varchar(50)
);
INSERT INTO "people" VALUES('Jose das Couves','jose@couves.com');
INSERT INTO "people" VALUES('Manoel Joaquim','manoel.joaquim@cafundo.com');
INSERT INTO "people" VALUES('Maria das Dores','maria@dores.com');
```

and fill it with `sqlite3 luasql-test < createdb.txt`

The next step is to create a simple LuaLaTeX document and read the file into the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode,booktabs}
\usepackage{luapackageloader}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
-- print(package.cpath)
package.cpath="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/?.so;"..package.cpath
-- print(package.cpath)
local luasql = require "luasql.sqlite3"
env = assert (luasql.sqlite3())
-- connect to data source
con = assert (env:connect("luasql-test"))
-- retrieve a cursor
cur = assert (con:execute"SELECT name, email from people")
-- print all rows, the rows will be indexed by field names
row = cur:fetch ({}, "a")
tex.sprint([[\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}\toprule]])
tex.sprint([[Name & email \\\midrule]])
while row do
  tex.sprint(-2,row.name)
  tex.sprint("&")
  tex.sprint(-2, row.email)
  tex.sprint("\\\\")
  -- reusing the table of results
  row = cur:fetch (row, "a")
end
tex.sprint([[\bottomrule\end{tabular}]])
-- close everything
cur:close()
con:close()
env:close()
\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

NOTES:

1. It's important to note which version of Lua your LuaTeX installation
   corresponds to. One way of doing so is to check the linker.

   ```
   ldd $(which luatex) | grep lua
           libtexlua52.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtexlua52.so.5 (0x00007fe2d3d80000)
   ```

   The "lua52" string is the significant one. So in the case of the TeX 
   Live 2019 prerelease in Debian Buster, it's Lua 5.2
2. The major issue with topskip's answer is that LuaTeX doesn't search
   the paths given in the standard system Lua paths, which correspond
   (in Lua) to `package.path` and `package.cpath`. LuaTeX searches
   paths  using TeX's  [kpathsea's
   library](https://tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html) to search, like
   everything else in TeX. Which is different from `package.path` and
   `package.cpath` in general.

   As of 2017, there is a simple solution, namely [`luapackageloader`](https://github.com/deepakjois/luapackageloader).
   This  package seems remarkably obscure for something that solves a
   basic issue. It's currently mentioned in exactly 2 Q/A threads on
   TeX SE. It's also included in TeX Live 2019, and the Debian package 
   `texlive-luatex`.

   Under normal circumstances, `package.path` and `package.cpath` are
   ignored by LuaTeX. For some reason they have a default value in
   LuaTeX, as you can check by running `print(package.path)`. If you
   include the `luapackageloader` package, then LuaTeX *will* search in
   the paths in `package.path` and `package.cpath as applicable. For
   those who aren't familiar with Lua, you can write Lua modules in Lua,
   or in C.  PATH corresponds to the former, CPATH to the latter.

   So, one just needs to add the path for the desired module to PATH or
   CPATH. By way of illustration, this is what I did for the module in
   topskip's example. Here I use `dlocate` to search for all files in
   all installed Debian packages containing the string `luasql`, and
   then grepped for `sqlite3.so`.

   ```
   dlocate luasql | grep sqlite3.so

   lua-sql-sqlite3:amd64:
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.1/luasql/sqlite3.so
   lua-sql-sqlite3:amd64:
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/luasql/sqlite3.so
   lua-sql-sqlite3:amd64:
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.3/luasql/sqlite3.so
   ```

   Or one could simply search the package `lua-sql-sqlite3`.

   ```
   dpkg -L lua-sql-sqlite3 | grep sqlite3.so
   ```

   Then I added `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/` to CPATH with

   ```
   package.cpath="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/?.so;"..package.cpath
   ```

   since, as already noted, the LuaTeX installation corresponds to Lua 
   5.2.

   A better general solution would be to automatically add PATH and
   CPATH to `package.path` and `package.cpath`. If I find a way to do
   so, I'll edit.

   See also a couple of additional answers mentioning `luapackageloader`. 
   One, [an answer to "Using LuaLaTeX and SQLite3"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372134/3406), is apparently by the author of 
   `luapackageloader`. There is also [an answer to "How to animate SVG paths as an animated PDF with animate?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474622/3406).

   Most of the work in `luapackageloader` is clearly done at the Lua end, with the code in `luapackageloader.lua`.
3. This code in topskips's answer no longer works.

   ```
       require("luasql.sqlite3")   
       env = assert (luasql.sqlite3())
   ```

   Instead one needs to use

   ```
       local luasql = require "luasql.sqlite3"
       env = assert (luasql.sqlite3())
   ```

   See, for example, the question  [uasql nil value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854971/luasql-nil-value)
   and particularly  the comment 
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854971/luasql-nil-value#comment17386385_10854971

   The `local` bit is optional, but I was informed that

   > modern convention is that required modules should not set globals, you should do `local foo = require "foo"`instead