# Accessing MySQL or SQLite from Lua(La)TeX

Tags: luatex, database, lua

I thought it would be possible to access MySQL or SQLite from Lua(La)TeX, but couldn't google up anything on the topic.

Please give me pointers to:

- Snippets / Examples / Documentation on that, if available
- Whether I should rather look this up in the Lua community

I explicitly list SQLite here, as I want to make this work for the low-tech users collaborating through DropBox or the like.

Comment: Context comes with an [SQL interface](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/refs/heads/origin:/tex/context/base/util-sql.lua) out of the box.

Comment: @phg ... so does PHP - common denominator: They are both not LaTeX.

Comment: a) That’s a destestable comparison by any conceivable moral standard; b) it’s a lot easier to port Context code to Latex than PHP, so it should be relevant as a starting point; c) you surrounded the “La” in “Lua(La)TeX” in parentheses and omitted the “Latex” tag, so my comment is 100% relevant to the question as you put it.

Comment: See my answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48233/243

Answer (score 5):

The SQLite organization provides the [LuaSQLite](http://lua.sqlite.org/index.cgi/index) library, with documentation and examples. I guess if you want more help with the `lua` code itself the Lua community is more suited for more in depth support, if further questions are about the implementation with `lualatex` this is an at least equally appropriate site to ask your questions.

Answer (score 1):

[LuaSQL](http://keplerproject.org/luasql/) can be used with LuaTeX.