# Creating a LaTeX Template which is filled by a script

Tags: automation

I have create some sort of Template I'm using for my reports. The Data shown in those document is collected by a script running on a webserver.

I was wondering if there is an appropriate method for creating the whole reports via scripting. My first intention was to simply replace strings withing the `.tex`file but this seems to be a very dirty method.

I'm considering writing my own tool which should be capable of setting some sort of variables within the `.tex` file. Maybe in combination with a package created for this purpose. The final goal would be, to run everything as a web-service giving you the ability to simply download the finished report.

Are there any Tools which are already doing this?

Comment: Related blog post by Paulo: http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2012/03/generating-latex-code-with-a-template-engine/

Comment: Have a look for "template engines" like Jinja2 (based on Python) or others. I have made good experience with Jinja2 which helped me to print dozens of German tax forms. I'll create a more detailed answer later.

Comment: Maybe this could help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48193/reading-data-from-a-relational-database-into-a-latex-table/153098#153098

Comment: It would be possible to store the data in JSON objects, this could do the work. I'll definitely try it.

Comment: I usually generate a portion of the TeX file which I load by one or more `\input` commands in the main TeX file. From time to time I generate whole TeX file which is processed by some TeX engine afterwards.

Comment: VtC as duplicate as discussed http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20085347#20085347