# latex presentation: control appearing each character with specific timing

Tags: presentations, multimedia, slideshow, transition, teaching

I like to create (slide) presentation that automatically appears each "**word**" or "**character**" one by one from left to right with a specific speed (without using "\pause" pressing each time the bottom "space" key), which seems that I am writing on a sheet of paper when I explain something to a student. I want to use this feature, if exist, for teaching math purpose.

I hope I could explain what I meant. If not please let me know.

Let me give an example:

```
Let $a,b,c>0$. assume the quadratic equation
$$
ax^2+bx+c=0.
$$
```

Now I like to have PDF output being start with the word "Let" after some mili-seconds "a," again after some mili-seconds $b,$ then "c" and so on.

For instance I want the above example takes one minute (less or more) to finish the slide and wait for me to command to go for the next page.

Here

[recorded sample video](https://filebin.net/2uagg4kqkcqrit3f/06.07.2020_10.56.45_REC.mp4?t=v0vsta19)

I uploaded a recorded video from what I meant one part is separated by **word** the other by **character**. I used too many

> \pause

command to get this :(

Comment: +1 Your question is interesting. Nevertheless, from a pedagogical point of view, students memorize more easily what the teacher writes on the blackboard itself. Indeed, memorization is a complex process that involves the teacher's gestures, voice, way of moving, etc. Displaying text as if you were writing on the blackboard yourself does not have the same effect as writing it on the blackboard yourself.
So, personally, I post parts of lessons that the students copy verbatim and others that I write myself, such as calculations and examples.

Comment: @AndréC, thanks for your comment. Of course the voice and explanation over the text is important. My question is more related when I want to teach via internet online (live) meeting with him/her, but of course they may download the PDF files if they want to study later by their own.

Comment: related : [How to animate SVG paths as an animated PDF with animate?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/473936/138900)