# Latex and no sql database

Tags: database

good evening, 
I want to connect no sql database to latex in other to generate some pdf file with generated data from this database?
have you got any ideas how I can do it?
regard

Comment: This depends very much on what database server you use.  If there is client software in Lua, you can use LuaTeX to connect to the server from within the TeX run.

Comment: Related? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48193/2693

Comment: R can connect to SQL servers in several ways, so via `knitr` it should be possible.

Comment: Often it is better to do this in a different language, for example python, and then use that language to extract the data and generate/fill in the latex file before you compile it. Then there are less things that can go wrong

Comment: @daleif I've an issue with Lua and mongoDB I asked if there are an other way to make that?

Comment: And that is what I'm saying, there might be a bigger pool to get help from if you leave lua