# Switching to an "enhanced" latex

Tags: xetex, luatex

I'm a long time LaTeX user and have a pretty efficient workflow already set up for writing LaTeX document, however I've pretty much missed the entire wave of "alternate" and "enhanced" LaTeX replacements like LuaTeX and XeTeX. I've been wanting to try out a new typesetting engine, but am interested in making a switch only to something that I can keep using long term.

For someone writing for the sciences, what would be an efficient path to switch from LaTeX, minimizing the dip in productivity? Particularly, how well do existing LaTeX packages (of most interest - publisher specific packages like `revtex`) interface with LaTeX alternatives? Are there any distinct advantages that someone writing for scientific publication or engineering documentation would find useful in other *TeX's ?

Comment: Subjective flag would be understood, but I believe the question is useful enough to warrant keeping

Comment: As far as I'm aware, XeTeX and LuaTeX are entirely backwards-compatible, so you can take your old documents and compile then with the new engines straight away. The only potential problem I can see is if you use `inputenc`, since these engines use the Unicode input encoding.

Comment: Next questions and answers won't solve your problem but can help you: [differences-between-luatex-context-and-xetex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36/1952), [Drawbacks of XeTeX/LuaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3094/1952), [abandon-latex2e-for-latex3-or-luatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59541/1952) and some more cliking on `xetex` or `luatex` tags on right side of this page.

Comment: Publishers tend to be very conservative.  I am not aware of any that will accept luatex / xetex specific files.

Comment: Some related questions: [Using LuaTeX as a replacement for pdfTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32295) and [Using XeLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21736).

Comment: An additional *advantage* of using `LuaLaTeX` over `pdfLaTeX` is that `LuaLaTeX` lets you use various recent packages, such as `showhyphens` and (shameless self-advertising alert!) `selnolig`, which require the added features and capabilities of the LuaTeX engine. An additional *downside* of LuaLaTeX maybe worth mentioning is that it's still in (late!) beta and therefore that some of its features may be subject to significant change -- probably for the better overall, but still worth knowing about before you take the plunge.

Answer (score 8):

The main advantages of using `xelatex` or `lualatex` (my personal favorite) instead of `pdflatex` are:

- you get native utf8 compatibility,
- you can use any OpenType and TrueType font, i.e. basically any font,
- you can use advanced font features, such as special ligatures, alternate glyphs, etc, and
- you can easily add code scripts inside your TeX files, and these can even access TeX internals (`lualatex` only, and only for the braves :)),
- you make the switch to a modern TeX engine, something you will anyways have to do one day (`lualatex` is the official successor to `pdflatex` AFAIK).

As for drawbacks / incompatibilities, there are no real technical hurdles that should prevent someone from switching IMHO:

- <strike>`pstricks` doesn't work, but `pgf/tikz` is superior anyways,</strike>
- most of the features of `microtype` are now available (under `lualatex`, only character protrusion is available under `xelatex`) and the few remaining are being worked on,
- `polyglossia` is not a perfect replacement yet for `babel` but it's not that of a showstopper in my view, and
- last time I checked, `xe`- / `lualatex` replacement for `CJK` weren't yet up to par with it, but it's irrelevant for most western users (and I assume you are).

So, the biggest showstopper in my opinion is not that *something* is preventing you to migrate, but *someone*: most journals who only accept `pdflatex`-compatible input and will probably be the last ones to make the switch, your thesis supervisor who is too old to learn something new, your colleagues who are too lazy to, ... :(

For detailed lists about the switches from `pdflatex` to `xe`- or `lualatex`, check these questions:

- [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2984/10102)
- [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28642/10102)
- [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87155/10102)

Comment: `pstricks` works fine with `xelatex`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Oh, I always thought it didn't... Well, that's one less reason not to switch!

Comment: Most of `microtypes` features don't work with XeLaTeX, at least according to the doc as I understand: Letterspacing, font expansion, interword spacing and kerning.

Comment: @JuriRobl True, just corrected my answer for that. I am a `lualatex` user, and thought that the features were also implemented for / in `xelatex`.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things you have to change in your document, like the `fontenc` package. Also there are some packages which you don't work or have only limited functionality (at least at the moment), like microtype. And LuaLaTex compiling takes ages compared to pdflatex (at least in my experience).

You can on the other hand use any fonts installed on your system, and there are some packages only available for LuaLaTex. And of course you can use lua with LuaLaTex, which is really easy compared to programming in (La)TeX.

Answer (score 3):

It is not so much an *either/or* as it is a need of specific features, as summarized by Xavier.  There's not much difference.  For instance with XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX you can more readily choose system fonts, but with XeLaTeX you're missing some `microtype` features (its biggest drawback).  Both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX are notably slower on my system with large documents.  So sometimes I use pdfLaTex while drafting and switch to XeLaTeX towards the end.

It's pretty easy to make documents that can be used with different TeX flavors, for instance using the `iftex` package.

Here's an example of a document that various over the engine.
[image: XeLaTeX vs. PdfLaTeX]

```
\documentclass[paper=a6]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX% when compiling with pdflatex
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[largesmallcaps, fulloldstylenums, widermath]{kpfonts}
\else% when compiling with xe- or lualatex
  \usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Numbers=OldStyle}
  \setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\fi
\addtokomafont{section}{\rmfamily\ifPDFTeX\else\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Lining}}\fi}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello World}
This is \ifPDFTeX Kpfonts \else Linux Libertine and \TeX{} Gyre
Pagella Math \fi
\(y=x^2+\epsilon\)
\end{document}
```